# A smarter way to do this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a a map on my site, and clicking regions a class should be toggled, on both hover and click, I've made a jQuery solution to do this, however, I think it can be done a bit smarter than i've done it? my HTML output is this:

```
<div class="mapdk">
                <a data-class="nordjylland" class="nordjylland" href="#"><span>Nordjylland</span></a>
                <a data-class="midtjylland" class="midtjylland" href="#"><span>Midtjylland</span></a>
                <a data-class="syddanmark" class="syddanmark" href="#"><span>Syddanmark</span></a>
                <a data-class="sjaelland" class="sjalland" href="#"><span>Sjælland</span></a>
                <a data-class="hovedstaden" class="hovedstaden" href="#"><span>Hovedstaden</span></a>
            </div>
```

And my jQuery looks like:

```
if ($jq(".area .mapdk").length) {
    $jq(".mapdk a.nordjylland").hover(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass("nordjylland");
    }).click(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass("nordjylland");
    });
    $jq(".mapdk a.midtjylland").hover(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass("midtjylland");
    }).click(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass("midtjylland");
    });
}
```

The thing is, that with what i've done, i have to make a hover and click function for every link i've got - I was thinking I might could keep it in one hover,click function, and then use something like $jq(this) ? But not sure how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this selector

```
if ($jq(".area .mapdk").length) {
    $jq(".mapdk a").hover(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass($jq(this).attr("class"));
    }).click(function () {
        $jq(".mapdk").toggleClass($jq(this).attr("class"));
    });

}
```

Comment: Why have you specified data-class attribute

Comment: Ohh, that's just a legacy thing, dont need it anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `$jq(this)`. `$jq(this)` refers to the element which called the event listener.

For example:

```
$jq(".mapdk a").hover(function () {
        $jq(this).parents(".mapdk").toggleClass($jq(this).data("class"));
    }).click(function () {
        $jq(this).parents(".mapdk").toggleClass($jq(this).data("class"));
    });
```

To break it down:

- `$jq(this)` calls the element which was hovered (ie. the anchor element).
- `.parents(".mapdk")` finds the first parent with the class `.mapdk`
- `$jq(this).data("class")` gets the value of `data-class` from your anchor element

Comment: you still have to have one for each class of the anchor tags

Comment: @RuneFS I'm not sure if your comment is still relevant? I saved my answer before I had finished doh!

Comment: it's not :) however you still have two issues. OP is using `$jq` and not `$` so it might be that your `$(this)` has a different meaning on his side and you are (potentially) not toggling the class on the same set of elements as OP is. However as I note in my answer I believe this to be a bug in OP code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the each function of jQuery to iterate all anchor tags within .mapdk

**DISCLAIMER** I'm assuming you only wish to set the class of the parent .mapdk. If you have multiple with that class (that aren't parents of the anchor) then the below will not work as your code but I'm assuming you wouldn't want to set the class for all .mapdk regardless of which anchor you hover/click.

```
//Since the function is the same for all event handlers let's just declare that once
var handler = function () {
        var $this = $jq(this);
        $this.parents(".mapdk").toggleClass($this.attr("class"));
};
//find all the anchor tags within .mapdk that has a class specified
$jq(".mapdk a[class]").each(function{
    this.hover(handler).click(handler);
});
```